# Excel find function to find whole words from an active cell containing sentences, and not individual characters

Tags: vba, excel, find, wildcard

Attached is my code so far. My issue is that I can't seem to get the macro to compare only whole words sheet(2) column B activecell (which contains more than one word within the cell) to the range (column A) in sheet(1) - which is a list of whole words (pictured below). Everything else in the code works fine but at present it only works for exact matches?

I have tried using the wildcard approach but it seems to match any characters whereas I need it to compare whole words from the sentences (which are varying each time in the active cell).

Any tips on what I can add so that the countif function finds whole words instead of characters etc? The same problem is for the Find function, where it will only find the exact match and return errors if it doesn't find exactly that.

```
    Sub FMEATest1()

Dim count As Integer
Dim count2 As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim FML As Range
Dim i As Range
'Dim m As Integer
Dim a As Range
Dim b As Integer
Dim FML2 As Range
Dim WrdArray() As String
Dim k As Range
Dim j As Range
Dim Splitsentence As Range
Worksheets(1).Activate


Range(("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Select

Set FML = Selection

Worksheets(2).Activate

Range("B3").Activate

Do Until ActiveCell.value = ""
Set i = ActiveCell
WrdArray() = Split(i, , , vbTextCompare)
Set Splitsentence = WrdArray().value

count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(FML, Splitsentence)

     'm = (ActiveCell.Row) + count - 1

    n = Selection.Rows.count

    Do Until n = (count)

     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
     Set a = Selection.Offset(1, 0)
        ActiveCell.COPY
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).value = ActiveCell.value
        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
     Range(i, a).Select

    n = Selection.Rows.count
    Loop

    'Copying Failure Modes for each Keyword
         Lookfor = ActiveCell.value & "*"
         Worksheets(1).Activate
         Cells.Find(What:=Lookfor, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False).Select

        Set FML2 = Selection
        Set j = ActiveCell
     count2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(FML2, j)
     m = Selection.Rows.count
     Do Until m = (count)

    Set k = Selection.Offset(1, 0)
        Range(j, k).Select
        m = Selection.Rows.count
    Loop

    Selection.Offset(0, 1).COPY
    Worksheets(2).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial


    ActiveCell.Offset(n, -1).Activate

    Loop

    End Sub
```

The difficulty is that the activecell contains a sentence and this sentence varies each time as in the example below, but I need the macro to match whole key words from column B in sheet(2) to Column A in sheet (1).

Can someone please make my images publically visible please?

[image]
[image]

So I would be looking for the code to be able to find the word "charge" from cell B3 out of the whole sentence (and get it to find it in column A of sheet(1)). And the word "Hold" from B4 from the whole sentence. These can change so much so I can't manually input them into the find function I need to reference the activecell.

The final solution of the code should give the following result (I've given two examples for "charge" and "hold"):

[image]

Comment: Are your sentences made of words separated by *space* characters??

Comment: Yes they are, I hope the images are available to you? The sentence examples are in the column B and C image (Sheet 2)

Comment: How about the 'InStr' Function?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/instr-function

Comment: Or `Split` and loop.

Comment: Hey @sporc, thanks for the reply! I have been researching for days on what to do, but just hoped there was a simpler way. I am by no way good at VBA and have tried everything to get it to compare / researched. Any advice would be helpful :)

Comment: Hi @SJR, I couldn't find much information on the split function - well enough for an amateur to understand. Any tips on simplifying the function? If there was a way to get a wild card on the "ActiveCell.Value" I feel that would work but I tried everything and nothing helped.

Comment: Try doing things the other way round - rather than trying to look up part of `i` in `FML`, loop through `FML` and try and find those values within `i` .

Comment: Hi @bobajob, I considered that option, but I guess the underlying problem is that I am too out of my depth with coding such comparisons? I tried using Strcomp etc but since I am learning as I am doing I failed miserably. Is this change a simple change that I am missing ?

Comment: Split will turn your string into an array of words and then you can loop through each to see if any of them match the column A entries, and @bobajob's approach is better.

Comment: @SJR so if I referenced my activecell, will it split the sentence using the space characters? I will give it a go here, but it may take me a while lol. Yes I will see what I can do with bobajob's advice also. Thanks

Comment: Yes, `Split("The quick brown fox")` returns an array of four elements each containing one word. You can specify a delimiter but by default it is a space so you need not include it. If you get stuck, post back with the code you've tried.

Comment: Hi @SJR, just one last pointer, once I split the activecell up, how do I reference each of the words within the split so that I can get each one to loop through? This is particularly difficult for the countIf part. The code I have attempted will foloow

Comment: Do Until ActiveCell.value = ""
Set i = ActiveCell
WrdArray() = Split(i, , , vbTextCompare)
Set Splitsentence = WrdArray.value

count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(FML, Splitsentence)

Comment: Can you add the code to your question please as it's hard to read in a comment. You have an array so array(0), array(1) etc where array is the whatever variable name you assign to the split. I'll post some code in a bit. Can you explain why you have repeated items in column A? And what is the ultimate desired result of the code?

Comment: I have repeated items in column A as for that specific word eg "charge" there are a certain number of associated terms with it (which are found in the same sheet in column B). I repeated the word to make it easier to find all of the associated terms with that specific word, as if there were spaces the code wouldn't be able to search all of Column A that is used? The ultimate desired result of the code is long - I will post in another comment

Comment: The ultimate desired result is to compare activecell Column B Sheet (2) with column A Sheet(1). Then count how many matches there are to the word e.g. "charge", input the number of rows into sheet(2) below the activecell = number of matches. Then once inserted, find the matches and copy the column B in sheet (1) beside the matches, to sheet (2) in column C (column and cells beside the activecell in sheet(2)). - I have got it to do everything but being able to find key words out of the sentences. Otherwise everything else works well.

Comment: @SJR Any further advice that you have possibly? Stumped at this one to be honest.

Comment: Forgot about this one. In terms of the output can you add to your screenshot what you would expect the code to produce because I'm not 100% clear currently? For "Charge the desired substance" would you expect B3 to B7 to be copied alongside?

Comment: Hey @SJR, I added the final output in the question - could someone please make it visible as I don't have that option as yet. Yes you are correct, it is to copy the column B (sheet 1) values for each match into sheet 2 (column C). Hope this makes it clearer

Comment: OK, but atm you have two consecutive entries in column B on sheet2 but in your output each of them would need to be repeated (5 and 3 times respectively) so are you ok to just move rows down to accommodate these extra rows? Would it be easier to put the results in a third sheet?

Comment: Yes I need the sentences to be copied down once the rows are added if that makes sense? To give the answer I put up above. Thanks

Comment: See suggested answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have assumed data as outlined in the comments so you may have to amend sheet names and ranges. Also depending on what other data you have in your sheet it may need some adjustment for the output, but if you mock up an example based on your screenshots it should work as desired.

```
Sub x()

Dim v, vOut(), i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, va, r As Range, r1 As Long

'Assumes list of words in A1/B1 and down on "Sheet1"
Set r =Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion

With Sheets("Sheet2") 'Assumes phrases in B1 and down on "Sheet2"
    v = .Range("B1", .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
    .Columns(2).ClearContents
End With

ReDim vOut(1 To UBound(v) * r.Rows.Count, 1 To 2)

For i = LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1)
    va = Split(v(i, 1))
    For j = LBound(va) To UBound(va)
       For r1 = 1 To r.Rows.Count
          If LCase(Application.Trim(va(j))) = LCase(r.Cells(r1, 1)) Then
             k = k + 1
             vOut(k, 1) = v(i, 1)
             vOut(k, 2) = r.Cells(r1, 2)
          End If
       Next r1
    Next j
Next i

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Resize(k, 2) = vOut 'Puts results in B1/C1 and down on "Sheet2"

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @SJR, this works for the first one, but stops at that?. Is it possible that it doesn't delete the entire column B in sheet 2 as this will be filled maybe down to 500 rows? Is there anyway for it to continue down through the whole range in column B until no more sentences are left.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that the document always starts on row 3 for sheet 2? I changed that in the code during my trial but I couldn't get the code to work through more than one sentence within column B

Comment: Can you do as I suggested above and try the code on a workbook set out just as you have done in your screenshots? I think the problems are artefacts of how your actual data are laid out - I can't see why it would stop after one unless it doesn't find any matches.

Comment: Hi, I inputted it into my workbook, and it stops after the first charge example. I then put "Hold" into cell B3 and it comes up "Type Mismatch" error. The clear contents means that it will stop on itself, as it clears it and then tries to compare against nothing? In my code I got it to compare and count the number in sheet 1, and then insert the number of rows -1 equal to that count.

Comment: It puts the data in an array and based on that so deleting the cells doesn't affect it. I don't really understand what you are doing differently - it works for me. When you say "stops", what exactly do you mean? Do you get any results, an error message...?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for any other key word (eg "hold" from sheet 1 column A) except "charge". It clears the column and will only ever generate 5 x "charge the desired substance." It also brings up a run-time error for any other word except charge?

Comment: We're going round in circles here. I don't know if you tested as I suggested. Also step through the code to check what it's doing, observe the values of variables etc, see if you can find the problem.

Comment: Ok so I went through the local window, testing as you said. I tried two "Charge the desired substance" and one "Hold for NLT 15 hrs". It returned only the "charge" values and deleted the "Hold" sentence - which I put in the row between each "Charge the desired substance" rows. It only seems to be able to account for the word charge and I couldn't tell why from the locals window? Also, is it possible that it doesn't delete the sentence that it doesn't recognize?

Comment: Do you have any gaps in the data in sheet1?

Comment: No I don't, the locals window is reading through 47 as well, which is how many rows are filled. I really can't understand why it only works for charge :/

Comment: I'm baffled too. See if you can see my test file http://www.filedropper.com/book2_5

Comment: I will set up an account and see if I can see your test file. Can I ask if you return the correct values and number of values for your test file when you use inert / hold for example, rather than charge?

Comment: I don't think you need to sign up, just download it?

Comment: This is really strange.. It works on one laptop of mine and not the other? Is the split / compare function sensitive to any formatting at all?

Comment: I think I have found the problem.. The code you supplied works really well for the list I gave you. If however, I make one change to column A in sheet 1, or column B in sheet 2, the code does not take account for it? Is this because it is an array?

Comment: Oops, something I forgot was that it is case sensitive. Easily remedied but could that account for your problems?

Comment: That could be part of the reason, no idea how that slots in though? It is odd because if I mix up any of order for "charge", "hold" and "inert" it will solve it. If I add in another row to the list, it doesn't account for it? Is there any way that you can have a code that will always take account of the full column A and B from sheet 1 i.e. the currentregion gets larger or smaller, if in the future I wanted to added more key words for instance?

Comment: I've made a change to handle the case thing. Currentregion automatically contracts and expands as you change data.

Comment: See that is what I have found from my research but it doesn't seem to be doing it - I have tried it on your workbook and I can't seem to get it to take account of any changes?

Comment: Lower case addition hasn't made any difference to the problem :(

Comment: I don't understand. I can add items to column A/B in sheet1 or column B in sheet2 and it works. You'll have to provide a specific example of what you're doing and what is not working.

Comment: I added "Temperature Ramp" to Column A in Sheet1 and "money" to ColB, and "Temperature Ramp for 1 hour" to Column B in sheet 2 - it did not take account for it when I ran the code. I also added an additional "Hold" in column A in sheet 1 and got no accountability for it either :/. I reset the code each time I make a change and nothing else happens everytime? Does the version of excel matter? I just can't understand how mine isn't working and I am using your workbook? All I need to do is hit the reset button? It isn't working on either laptops I have. I have excel 2010 if that changes anything

Comment: Ah, some light has dawned. The code currently assumes the value in col A of sheet 1 is a single word.

Comment: That would explain a lot. I've got it to work for additional single words added to column A, but strangely if I add another "Hold" it doesn't take account of the 4th one? It only ever outputs the same initial 3 as per the question? This is the same for "charge", and for "Inert." Hopefully some light is shed on these ones lol

Comment: Would the code need a split function in at the start for col A in sheet1 to account for more than one word?

Comment: Well it's more complicated than that because you have to match multiple words presumably in the right order and presumably adjacent. Might need a re-think and a new question building on this one but enumerating the various possibilities.

Comment: Hi @SJR, I would really appreciate any help that you could give! :)

Comment: Hi @SJR, shall I make another post regarding the updated problem at hand?

Comment: Well I suggested it some days ago so I should say so. Also, you don't have to accept my answer if it hasn't solved your problem, but don't be afraid to show your appreciation of help received here. It's how the site works.

Comment: Hi @SJR, apologies for the delayed appreciation. Thoroughly appreciate all the help and guidance you have offered so far on the question i posed! I accepted the answer as you answered what I initially put up, so hats off! Thanks again! I have posed another question to address the additional problem at -hand.